# xsl if test内での関数呼び出し

Tags: c#, xpath, xsl, xslt

下記のように、if関数の条件の中で所定の要素に別の関数(normalize-space)を適用し、その結果を比較に使用したいと思っています。
が、下記の記載を含むxslを適用したxmlをブラウザ上で表示することができません。(画面上真っ白になります)
下記の記述を削除すると正常に表示されます。
このような記述の仕方は不可能なのでしょうか？
また、もし代替案があればご教授いただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

なお、C#で読み込みを行いたいため、XSLのバージョンは1.0です。

```
<xsl:if test="element1/element2[element3/normalize-space(element4)='AAA']/element5 !=''">
～
</xsl:if>
```

追記
下記の通り、該当の要素に適用するtemplateを作ってみたのですが、
下記[]内には適用されないようで、ダメでした・・・
element1/element2[element3/element4='AAA']/element5

```
  <xsl:template match="element1/element2/element3/element4">
    <xsl:call-template name="normalizespace">
      <xsl:with-param name="string" select="." />
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="normalizespace">
    <xsl:param name="string" />
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($string)"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:if test="element1/element2[element3/normalize-space(element4)='AAA']/element5 !=''">
> ～
> </xsl:if>
> ```

とのことですが、XPathとして正しくないです。 `normalize-space()` は関数であり、関数呼び出しは`[`の直後とまでは言いませんが少なくとも`/`の直後には置けません。

```
<xsl:if test="element1/element2[normalize-space(element3/element4)='AAA']/element5 !=''">
～
</xsl:if>
```

と書く必要があります。